# How to manage a website with static menu and jQuery in content

Tags: jquery, html, layout

I have a website that has a menu div at the top and a side nav to the left. I've been using ajax `.load()` to replace the content div with whatever I want. I seem to be having a lot of issues when using jQuery in the content of those pages that get loaded in. Using the `.live()` function is helping but I keep getting unexpected behavior in places.

What is the right way to handle a menu/nav layout, without refreshing the entire page, and having no issues with the content that goes in? What frameworks do you guys use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is NOT ajax. You are saving a small amount of bandwidth and in return breaking back button navigation, caching, search engine indexing and making your whole site dependant on javascript. It's a crappy tradeoff.

Comment: Google happily supports dynamic content, providing you implement it properly. See: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html. Browser navigation can be manipulated using a library such as Sammy.js. Ajax is the future, you don't need to be worried about those kinds of things anymore. Just look at Twitter and Facebook.

Comment: Is there a way without using google or any framework? If not, is there something simple?

Comment: @Christian: 10 years ago people were saying the same thing about Flash, that all websites would be Flash one day. Today static sites outnumber Flash site more than 1000-1 and even that small percentage of Flash sites typically have a static content fallback. I actually make a good living converting sites FROM Flash back to HTML. If the OP wants to build a "Web Application" then so be it but the wording of the question indicates this is a more traditional website (static,menu,nav,content) and I think maybe he has bought into the "AJAX is the future" school of thought.